# three.js delay in updating local clipping planes

Tags: three.js

For realising a scrollable text container (using own bitmap fonts that are basically small sprite meshes) I am using local clipping planes.
When my text container moves the clipping planes are updated according to the global boundaries of my container.
This works perfectly except for fast movements. In this case the clipping planes are slightly delayed behind the container making the text shine through where it shouldn't.

My first thought was that the necessary code for updating the clipping planes might cause the delay.. but when I use apply this order: 
1. update the text box position
2. update the clipping planes
3. render()
the delay still exists

Is the reason maybe located in the threejs framework in how the actual clipping is applied?

Here's a small code snippet that shows how I compute my upper clippin plane using two helper meshes. The one is a plane that is positioned orthogonally on my text object (red plane in the picture). The other one is a THREE.Object3D that is positioned in the middle of the upper edge for computing the right plane constant.

```
//  get the world direction of a helper plane mesh that is located orthogonally on my text plane
var upperClippingPlaneRotationProxyMeshWordDirection = _this.upperClippingPlaneRotationProxyMesh.getWorldDirection();

//  get the world position of a helper 3d object that is located in the middle of the upper edge of my text plane
var upperClippingPlanePositionProxyObjPosition = _this.upperClippingPlanePositionProxyObj.getWorldPosition();

//  a plane through origin which makes it easier for computing the plane constant
var upperPlaneInOrigin = new THREE.Plane(upperClippingPlaneRotationProxyMeshWordDirection, 0);

var dist = upperPlaneInOrigin.distanceToPoint(upperClippingPlanePositionProxyObjPosition);
var upperClippingPlane = new THREE.Plane(upperClippingPlaneRotationProxyMeshWordDirection, dist*-1);

//  clipping plane update
_this.myUpperClippingPlane.copy(upperClippingPlane);
```

[picture showing the text object with clipping plane helpers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NunCs.jpg)

Comment: How about some code?

Comment: @pailhead I added a short code snippet with a picture demonstrating my concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for the delay. In my matrix updating code I only used updateMatrix() on the text object when it moves. To make sure that its child objects including the helper meshes update instantly I had to call updateMatrixWorld(true), this makes sure that the clipping planes are computed correctly

Comment: You had to call `updateMatrixWorld(true)` on which object? The object that has the material with the clipping planes?